# Python C API: Problems trying to build a dictionary

Tags: python, cpython, python-c-api, pyobject

I'm trying to build a Python dictionary using the C API but it seems it's not possible (Py_BuildValue returns a NULL object) to use a PyObject* as value.
I have a situation like the following:

```
#include <python3.5/Python.h>
...
PyObject *myList = PyList_New(1);
PyList_SetItem(myList, 0, Py_BuildValue("i", 1));
dict = Py_BuildValue("{siso}",
           "anInt", myInt,
           "aList", mylist);
```

I'm looking for a solution working with generic size of the list. I didn't find anything about this in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/arg.html) and also googling for hours. Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check what exception it's giving you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the wrong format spec. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/extending.html#building-arbitrary-values) is an example.

So, in order to build a dictionary, you do it like so:

```
int a_c_int; // 1
PyObject *a_python_list; // [1]
// ...
Py_BuildValue("{s:i,s:O}",  # note the capital O ;)
          "abc", a_c_int, 
          "def", a_python_list);
```

returns the python dict

```
{'abc': 1, 'def': [1]}
```

Comment: I've tried  that but it doesn't work. Did you tried your code?

Comment: I have not but it's literally copied from where I linked. Have you read this? `O (object) [PyObject *] Pass a Python object untouched (except for its reference count, which is incremented by one). If the object passed in is a NULL pointer, it is assumed that this was caused because the call producing the argument found an error and set an exception. Therefore, Py_BuildValue() will return NULL but won’t raise an exception. If no exception has been raised yet, SystemError is set.`

Comment: It seems that you also didn't read well enough the documentation because the 'o' do not work  but the 'O' yes! So, correct your answer and I'll mark it as solved ;)

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. In my defence it can be hard to tell the difference `o` and `O` when reading. Sorry about that; I'll edit the post.

Comment: You can double check [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/arg.html) that the 'O' is mentioned only as upper case